# C++ : What type of Identifier to be used?

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I am having a problem determining what type of identifier to be used in the following code. I have taken the code sample from [Microsoft UWP blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt465734.aspx)

But I can't seem to understand how to implement it? 
So please help me getting it right. Thanks

```
stackCount // is undefined in following code.


void StartPage::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e)
{
    auto rootFrame = dynamic_cast<Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame^>(Window::Current->Content);

    Platform::String^ myPages = "";

    if (rootFrame == nullptr)
        return;

    for each (PageStackEntry^ page in rootFrame->BackStack)
    {
        myPages += page->SourcePageType.ToString() + "\n";
    }

    stackCount->Text = myPages; // stackCount is undefined here

    if (rootFrame->CanGoBack)
    {
        // If we have pages in our in-app backstack and have opted in to showing back, do so
        Windows::UI::Core::SystemNavigationManager::GetForCurrentView()->AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
        Windows::UI::Core::AppViewBackButtonVisibility::Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        // Remove the UI from the title bar if there are no pages in our in-app back stack
        Windows::UI::Core::SystemNavigationManager::GetForCurrentView()->AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
        Windows::UI::Core::AppViewBackButtonVisibility::Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is C++/CLI, not C++

Comment: What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: stackCount is undefined.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc this is C++/CX, not C++/CLI

Comment: Can someone please help me getting an answer? Please... Thankyou

Comment: where is `stackCount` declared?

Comment: I don't know the answer to it because I am not an expert in this. I don't really know how to declare it in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `stackCount` is a multi-line `TextBlock` given that the sample sets the `Text` property. Add it in your XAML page.

Comment: I changed the `stackCount` to a `string` and it worked okay.